# addClass / removeClass not working

Tags: jquery

I have a problem for use this two jquery functions, so this is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Wv6gN/5/

and my js code :

```
$("a#slidingMenuButton.noState").click(function() {

$("i.fa-bars").addClass("textToLeft");
 $("a#slidingMenuButton").addClass("BtextToLeft").removeClass("noState");
    alert("lol1");

});


$("a#slidingMenuButton.BtextToLeft").click(function() {

   $("i.fa-bars").removeClass("textToLeft").addClass("textToRight");       $("a#slidingMenuButton").removeClass("BtextToLeft").addClass("noState");
  alert("lol2");

});
```

it's always the first onclick event that is made. why the addClass/removeClass not working ?

Comment: The event handlers are bound to the elements that match at the time they are bound. Changing the classes later will ***not*** affect the event handlers at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.on` so that you can bind to a dynamically created element. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wv6gN/6/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#slidingMenuButton.BtextToLeft', function () {
    $("i.fa-bars").removeClass("textToLeft").addClass("textToRight");
    $("a#slidingMenuButton").removeClass("BtextToLeft").addClass("noState");
    alert("lol2");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put these together into one function

```
$("a#slidingMenuButton").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('noState') {
      $("i.fa-bars").addClass("textToLeft");
      $("a#slidingMenuButton").addClass("BtextToLeft").removeClass("noState");
      alert("lol1");
 }
else {
    if($(this).hasClass('BtextToLeft') {
      $("i.fa-bars").removeClass("textToLeft").addClass("textToRight");           
      $("a#slidingMenuButton").removeClass("BtextToLeft").addClass("noState");
      alert("lol2");
     }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `toggleClass` instead.

```
$("a#slidingMenuButton.noState").click(function() {
  $("i.fa-bars").addClass("textToLeft");
  $("a#slidingMenuButton").toggleClass("BtextToLeft").toggleClass("noState");
  alert("lol1");
});
```

`toggleClass` will remove the class if it's there and add it when it's not. Here's your updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wv6gN/10/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the elements with either 'delegate' or 'on' in your usage. The reason being is that delegate or on will bind your elements NOW and IN THE FUTURE, as they exist and/are created. This is useful for elements that are updated alot or change classes etc...

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

When you set up your initial handlers those elements, in how you try to access them, do not exist.

So, you will need to change your code to: http://jsfiddle.net/Wv6gN/12/

update your code here: as others have noted. Use the ".on" method.

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a#slidingMenuButton.BtextToLeft', function () {
```